# Only show everything inbetween symbols

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I am looking to striong everything berfore and after symbols.

So here would be my text.

```
[sourcecode language='']%1982%<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>%1982%[/sourcecode]
```

And the result i need is

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

So it strips out all characters before and after the symbol `%1982%`

And help please on how to do this????

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it using the following

```
<?php 
$update = get_the_content();                                        
$arr = explode('%1982%',$update);
//print_r($arr);                                
echo $arr[1];
?>
```